# Replace XML values in bash in linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following XML data:

```
<info>
    <data>
        <name>my_image</name>
        <value>site.com/image1.img</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>my_link</name>
        <value>site.com/p_info</value>
    </data>
</info>
```

I want to replace all the site.com to siteimag.com of every my_image value (just for the my_image attributes).

So the result will be:

```
<info>
    <data>
        <name>my_image</name>
        <value>siteimag.com/image1.img</value>
    </data>
    <data>
        <name>my_link</name>
        <value>site.com/p_info</value>
    </data>
</info>
```

How can it be done with sed command?

Thanks.

Comment: parsing xml with sed is bad idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed '/my_image/{n;s/site.com/siteimag.com/}' file
```

Brief explanation,

- `/my_image/`: search the line contained "my_image"
- Once the string searched,

  - read the next line by using the command `n`.
  - `s/site.com/siteimag.com/`: do the substitution

Answer (score 5):

The right way is using xml parsers like **xmlstarlet**:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//data/name[text()='my_image']/following-sibling::value" \ 
-v "$(sed 's/site/&imag/' <(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//data/name[text()='my_image']/following-sibling::value" file.xml))" file.xml
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
  <data>
    <name>my_image</name>
    <value>siteimag.com/image1.img</value>
  </data>
  <data>
    <name>my_link</name>
    <value>site.com/p_info</value>
  </data>
</info>
```

Answer (score 2):

The same XML document can be written and formatted in many different ways,
so using a simple text tool like `sed` to update it, would be very fragile and easy to break.

E.g. just adding an empty line between `name` and `value`, will break the naïve `sed` script above:

```
<data>
    <name>my_image</name>

    <value>site.com/image1.img</value>
</data>
```

It also can not really follow the `XML` structure, and will simply replace any `site.com` reference, if there is a `my_image` pattern in the line above it, even if it is in a comment:

```
<data>
    <name>my_link</name> <!-- Used to be "my_image" -->
    <value>site.com/p_info</value>
</data>
```

There are literally hundreds of other ways, the source XML can be modified, without changing it's meaning, to make it break or result in a false replacements.

To avoid that, you should use an XML-aware tool, to do the replacement, e.g. `xmlstarlet`:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
-u "//data/name[text()='my_image']/../value" \
-x "concat(substring-before(.,'site.com'),'sitemag.com',substring-after(.,'site.com'))"|
data.xml
```