# How do I configure liquibase to use relative path for the filename column on table DATABASECHANGELOG?

Tags: liquibase

I'm using liquibase version 3.4

After I execute a liquibase changeset, I see the following entry into the changelog

```
INSERT INTO DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE) VALUES ('1561715333', 'userx', 'C:/TeamCity.BuildAgent/work/CMSLiquibase/src/main/resources/releases/1/core/ddl/JIRA-1000-ADD_COLUMN.xml', SYSTIMESTAMP, 17, '7:762a7c8960445ef94da88c10a81acd79', 'addColumn', 'Adding column', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.4.0');
```

For filename, liquibase generates the full path "C:/TeamCity.BuildAgent/work/CMSLiquibase/src/main/resources/releases/1/core/ddl/JIRA-1000-ADD_COLUMN.xml" where as I want the relative path "src/main/resources/releases/1/core/ddl/JIRA-1000-ADD_COLUMN.xml"

The liquibase documentation says Filename should be "Path to the changelog. This may be an absolute path or a relative path depending on how the changelog was passed to Liquibase. For best results, it should be a relative path"

But I cannot find any code examples on where this has been configured.

Any idea where I can configure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute `logicalFilePath` in the `<databaseChangeLog>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd"

    logicalFilePath="my_changelog.xml"> <<<<HERE

    ....
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Unfortunately there is no global setting to do that. You need to take care to do that for every changelog file you have.

#### Caution

If you change that if you have already run your existing change logs, you need to change the values in the database! Liquibase detects a changeset with the combination of **filename**, author and id. So if you change the `logicalFilePath` for something that has already been run, Liquibase will think it's a new change log and will try to run all changesets in the file again.

Comment: I was hoping there was a global setting somewhere, to avoid adding this to hundreds of changesets.

Comment: @Navs: me too :( - but I don't think there is one.

Comment: Easily scripted though. Just run a script that adds the attribute. Recommend xmlstarlet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46768554/200987